# How to achieve the required XML serialisation?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

The following class:

```
    public class CodelistFilters
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray]
        public List<CodelistFilterAndElement> AndGroup;

    }
    public class CodelistFilterAndElement
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray]
        public List<CodelistFilterOrElement> OrGroup;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
        public string Relationship { get { return "And"; } }
    }

    public class CodelistFilterOrElement
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
        public List<CodelistFilter> CodelistFilters;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
        public string Relationship { get { return "Or"; } }
    }

    public class CodelistFilter
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
        public string Value1 { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
        public string Value2 { get; set; }

    }
```

gets serialised as

```
<CodelistFilters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<AndGroup>
    <CodelistFilterAndElement>
        <OrGroup>
            <CodelistFilterOrElement>
                <CodelistFilters>
                    <CodelistFilter Name="Description" Value1="test" />
                </CodelistFilters>
            </CodelistFilterOrElement>
        </OrGroup>
    </CodelistFilterAndElement>
</AndGroup>
```

Which I sort of understand. However, what I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<CodelistFilters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Group Relationship="And"> 
    <Group Relationship="Or">
        <CodelistFilters Name="Description" Value1="test" />
    </Group>
</Group>
```

How should I structure my C# class to achieve this? I've tried messing around with XmlAttributes and nested Lists but just end up with different versions of "wrong".

Comment: You should have the same number of classes as you have tags in xml.  You want two tags (Group, and CodelListFilters) yet you have four classes.

Comment: Thanks  jdweng, but I don't know how to code a class that is a list, as opposed to a class that contains a property that is a list.

Comment: A property is a child of a class.  In an XML a Tag is a child of another tag.  So in your xml Group is a Child of Group so in your class Group is also a child of Group.  In you case the Group class has two types of children (Group and CodeListFilters).  And in CodeListFilters there a two types of children (Group and CodeListFilters).  So youi only need two classes, not four.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If these were just single objects I could code them in that way. There can be many AndGroups and AndGroups can have many OrGroups whilst OrGroups can have many CodelistFilters. I don't know how to express that without having nested classes containing properties which are lists. Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: Don't get the coding and the structure confused.  First design the structures which are the two classes.  Then write the code to handle the issue that a class can have more than on type child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you need to have a 1:1 mapping between your XML and your classes. You only have 3 elements in your required XML, so you need 3 classes to represent these.

```
public class CodelistFilters
{    
    [XmlElement("Group")]
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Relationship { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Group")]
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CodelistFilter")]
    public List<CodelistFilter> CodelistFilters { get; set; }
}

public class CodelistFilter
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2MDo23) for a working demo.

Comment: Many thanks, Charles. The fiddle seems to give an "out of memory" exception. I think because the class Group has a list of Group objects.

Comment: @user489998 nope, fiddle works fine for me. Are you sure it was out of memory? The site does occasionally time out when running samples, you often just need to try again.

Comment: Just tried it again and it's working fine. Thanks again, Charles.